# What is the difference between Function.database and Firebase.database? When to use one over the other?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am starting off with firebase and I have been reading significant amount of sample codes. One thing I notice is that some sample uses functions.database and some uses firebase.database when getting reference data.

This for example uses functions.database
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

This one uses firebase.database
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Is there any functional advantage using one over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are used in two different contexts:

1. `functions.database` is used when you register/create a **Cloud Function** that triggers on events from a specific Firebase Realtime Database instance. So it is used in code that is **executed in the back-end**, on the Cloud Function platform.
2. On the opposite, `firebase.database()` is used **in the front-end**, with the Client JavaScript SDK. It is used to get an instance of `firebase.database.Reference`, in order to read/write data from/to the Firebase Realtime Database.

So it all depends on where you plan to execute your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know which one to use now.